# Can I dump Jello into a pan and boil it to get it to set?

Tags: gelatin

My jello isn't setting, probably because my 4 year old was angry about having to wait for the water to boil and I just gave in. Anyway, can I dump it all in a pan and boil the whole? Or is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My jello is not getting firm in the refrigerator](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/84360/my-jello-is-not-getting-firm-in-the-refrigerator)

Comment: @AMtwo that question is asking about the proper procedure, not how to salvage improperly made jello.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can boil the whole thing. You need to get the temperature high enough for the gelatine to activate. The reason jello reserves half the water is to cool it down faster and reduce set time, there's no issues adding all the water in the first place other than taking longer to cool down enough to set.

If you are in a hurry you can cool it down afterwards by putting it in an ice bath and stirring it for awhile.

Comment: You will sometimes get Jello colored stains in your boiling pot.